# How to extract url from text with ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a textfile with some text in it. Somewhere in the text there could be an complete URL starting with http:// or https://.

How can I convert the url to an URL tag?

Example Text: stackoverflow is great, so please visit http:// www.stackoverflow.com

Should be displayed as: stackoverflow is great, so please visit http://www.stackoverflow.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using this script for years and it works great. It uses RegEx to find URLs in strings.

```
function create_links(strText)
    strText = " " & strText
    strText = ereg_replace(strText, "(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[^ ,""\s<]*)", "$1<a href=""$2"" ref=""nofollow"">$2</a>")
    strText = ereg_replace(strText, "(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ ,""\s<]*)", "$1<a target=""_blank"" ref=""nofollow"" href=""http://$2"">$2</a>")
    strText = ereg_replace(strText, "(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)", "$1<a href=""mailto:$2@$3"">$2@$3</a>")
    strText = right(strText, len(strText)-1)
    strText = Replace(strText,"." & chr(34) & ">",chr(34) & ">")
    strText = Replace(strText,".)" & chr(34) & ">",chr(34) & ">")
    create_links = strText
end function

function ereg_replace(strOriginalString, strPattern, strReplacement)
    dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp
    objRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    ereg_replace = objRegExp.replace(strOriginalString, strReplacement)
    set objRegExp = nothing
end function
```

I have made a few alterations, but the original is here… http://www.ipaste.org/Ycc

Answer (score 0):

1. Find position/entrance of HTTP:// or HTTPS:// in text. See "InStr" function.
2. Find end position of URL, it could be SPACE char or some other char, like ";". (Space char not valid for sample that you provide).
3. Once you get URL, put it inside HTML  tag :) You could do this by using `Replace`, or, by concatenating the strings.

Comment: Part 1 and part 3 are clear and no problem. But howto do part 2 in an effective way?